# cursor not showing in TextField when using EmojiPicker

Tags: flutter, textfield, emoji

I have tried multiple emoji packages and this is the best I found. I just have one problem with it. when showing the `EmojiPicker` after assigning its controller the same as the `TextField`, the cursor is not showing. I know this is not a keyboard and there is no focusing on that `TextField` so this behaviour is expected but this is causing a small problem. I set the `maxLines` of the `TextField` to 5, os after 5 lines, the `TextField` won't go down as it is not focusing when using the emoji. Is there a way to solve this issue?